# Add a Jquery tab and make it Active

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

How would make an tab active as creating it?
The tabs bar appears but to show them content you have to click on it. 
I made this menu call to open an Jquery tab:

```
<a href="#" onClick="addTab('Expedi...','dialogs/grid_expedition.html','1100')">&nbsp;&nbsp;Expedition</a>
```

This creates the tab, but doesn't make it active.

This is the tabs.js:

```
//Global Variables
var tabTitle = null; //Title should start null
var tabs = null;
tabCounter = 1; //Counter of tab

//Function responsible to create a new Tab and insert the content loaded
function addTab(title, content, indexx) {
    var count = $("#tabs-"+indexx).length;
    var currentTab = indexx-1;
    if(count > 0 ){
        alert('Working tab');

}else{

var label = tabTitle.val() || title,
    id = "tabs-" + indexx,
    li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
    tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";
    tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);

    tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + content + "</p></div>");

    //to load data
    $.post( content, function( data ) {
      $( '#' + id ).html( data );
    }); 




     tabs.tabs("refresh");
    /* to Close the tab */
    tabs.delegate("span.ui-icon-close", "click", function () {
    var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
    $("#" + panelId).remove();

    //tabs.tabs("refresh"); 
});
tabCounter++;
}
}

// Function to initialize the tabs

function init() {
    tabTitle = $("#tab_title"), tabContent = $("#tab_content"), tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
    tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: -1});
    addTab('Principal', 'dialogs/features.html');
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
}
$('document').ready(init);
```

Also, when you close a tab, the last one dont be active too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programatically select which tab is currently active you can use:

```
tabs.tabs('option', 'active', 0);
```

With the last option being the index of the correct tab (0-based).

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked but only for the first opened tab. By the way, this broke all the content tab styles.

Comment: This will always only open the first tab as it's specifying the index of the first (0), changing this to 1 for example would open the second tab. With the styles I can't see how activating the tab would alter them in any way, are you sure this isn't a previous issue that this has revealed?